# Tensorflow get dimension info when using tf.map_fn() to iterate into a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say I have a tensor `ts` of shape `[s1, s2, s3]`, and I want to iterate into it with `tf.map_fn` as:

```
tf.map_fn(lambda dim1:
    tf.map_fn(lambda dim2:
        do_sth(dim, idx1, idx2)
    ,dim)
,ts)
```

The `idx1` and `idx2` above are index of dimension 0 and dimension 1 of `ts` that `do_sth()` is currently in. How can I get those? I want to get that as if I am doing something like:

```
for idx1 in range(s1):
    for idx2 in range(s2):
        tensor = ts[idx1][idx2]
        do_sth(tensor, idx1, idx2)
```

The reason why I cannot do it in that way is that most of the time `s1, s2, s3` are *unknown* (i.e., `ts` is of shape `(?, ?, t3)` or similar)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you add an extra dimension at the end and fill it with the indices before running your command.

This code (tested) adds the indices to the values multiplied by 10 and 100 for X and Y indices respectively:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

r = 3

a = tf.reshape( tf.constant( range( r * r ) ), ( r, r ) )
x = tf.tile( tf.cast( tf.lin_space( 0.0, r - 1, r )[ None, : ], tf.int32 ), [ r, 1 ] )
y = tf.tile( tf.cast( tf.lin_space( 0.0, r - 1, r )[ :, None ], tf.int32 ), [ 1, r ] )

b = tf.stack( [ a, x, y ], axis = -1 )

c = tf.map_fn( lambda y: tf.map_fn( lambda x: 
        x[ 0 ] + 10 * x[ 1 ] + 100 * x[ 2 ]
    , y ), b )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run( [ c ] )
    for x in res:
        print()
        print( x )
```

Outputs:

> [[  0  11  22]
>    [103 114 125]
>    [206 217 228]]